# Can I add row in handsontable by "insert" key.?

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I want to add a row in handsontable by "insert" key. is it possible to add row by a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. What you need to do is first capture the "insert" key event. You then call on your handsontable instance and use the `alter ('insert_row', index, amount)` where index is the position you want (set it to 0 to add to the top, for example), and amount is how many empty rows.

That should be it.

Answer (score 7):

this is my code and it is working perfectly.. :)

```js
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 45) { 
    var rowIndex = $('.currentRow').parent().index();

    hot.alter("insert_row", rowIndex);
  }
}); //insert key
```

"**.currentRow**" is my current selected row class, on current row tr > td.
That is why I use **$('.currentRow').parent()** 
because I wanted to get tr index.